# Android studio kotlin, cannot directly select ID without findViewById()

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to android studio and I'm leaning it from this [video](https://youtu.be/uRyvNKRkwbs)

At 50:45 he says that we can directly use the id without findViewById (), for him it shows just import that Id, but when I tried the same I'm not getting what he is getting. Can anyone tell me what's wrong, is that feature removed in the latest update??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"[kotlinx.android.synthetic is no longer a recommended practice. Removing in favour of explicit findViewById](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42121)"
So, this feature`s been deprecated almost a year ago.
The new recommended way of working with view tree is [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

Or you could write some lazy extension function that uses findViewById under the hood.

Comment: Don't use ``lazy`` for ``View``s, if a fragment's kept in memory but its views are destroyed, the lazy property is still holding onto the old view. So you get bugs (you're not interacting with the view you can see) and memory leaks. I've been tripped up by that a few times - use ``lateinit`` instead for anything with a shorter lifetime than the fragment / activity

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Kotlin Android Extensions  [check here](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/)  or with the help of [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) or [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) you can just use the id directly in to your java activity class

Answer (score 1):

The way you're talking about is Kotline Extensions for view, for which you apply it in the build.gradle file using `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`, sync the project as prompted by the Android studio and it starts working.

But, Kotlin extensions has also been deprecated for view binding which is null-safe, also easy to implement and better.

To read about view binding, read the Android documentation on ViewBinding [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and about migrating [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration). You can also go with [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/migrating-the-deprecated-kotlin-android-extensions-compiler-plugin-to-viewbinding-d234c691dec7) to help with setting up Android view binding.